# User profile empty in HttpContext in azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, auth0

I am using an azure web app service with my identity provider Auth0.
I got this working but whenever I login in my website hosted on azure the user profile is not loaded in HttpContext.
This is working locally in IIS Express.
Any idea what I might be missing?

This is my code to get the logged in user profile:

```
[Inject]
    private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; set; }
    private string loginId;

    /// <summary>
    /// On initialized
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadInvoiceTypes();
        this.loginId = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
    }
```

I did a bit of logging in the website and it seems that the HttpContext is null.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is advised in blazor to use the AuthenticationStateProvider.
This is giving me the logged in user in azure as I expected it should be.

```
    protected string loginId;

    [Inject]
    private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthProvider { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        this.loginId = authState.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I suggest that when you ask a question next time, the question should be clearly stated, blazor was not mentioned from the beginning to the end of the post question, and it was mentioned when answering the answer, which is very unfriendly.

Answer (score 2):

**Please see my test results first.**

Below is my test code.

```
public string test()
{
    var obj = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    this.loginId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier")?.Value;
        return loginId;
}
```

You can see my test result by gif.

[image]

What I have try just add `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` in `Startup.cs`.

For more details, you can refer to the blogs, it works for me.

[Accessing HTTPContext in ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/05/accessing-httpcontext-asp-net-core/)

And you also can [download my sample code to test it](https://github.com/Jason446620/HttpContextAccessor), hope my answer can help you.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the input but locally everything is working. When I publish to azure the HttpContext is empty.